# com.sun.kvem.midletsuite.invalidjadexception reason = 36 error in opening jar file

Tags: java-me

Hi Everyone I have a client server interaction in J2ME . When i run the application on the emulator i have a error like this

com.sun.kvem.midletsuite.invalidjadexception reason = 36 error in opening jar file

I am unable to find the solution .I searched in the google but it is not giving any appropriate soluion.

Kindly help me .I am searching for the past three days. Kindly give some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception usually comes from having a malformed .jar, .jad or possibly .mf file. https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=7276882 has a list of possible solutions to try.